# ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''20,99''

Tags: python, string, csv, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe that looks like this with 13000 rows

```
print(df)
```

```
           Date       Price   Nation
0    01/01/2018    -5.000,73  Spain
1    01/01/2018        15,60  Italy
3    01/01/2018        14,13  Italy
4    01/01/2018        12,53  Spain
5    01/01/2018        16,64  Italy
6    01/01/2018        22,48  Italy
7    01/01/2018        24,30  Italy
8    01/01/2018        24,88  Spain
9    01/01/2018        31,40  Italy
10   01/01/2018        18,74  Italy
```

Price Column is a `non-null object`
I removed all the white spaces and dropped al the empty rows
I tried to work only with the price column converting from a Series to a String

```
string=df['Price'].to_string()
print(string)
```

```
0        -5.000,73
1            15,60
3            14,13
4            12,53
5            16,64
6            22.48
7            24.30
8            24.88
9            31.40
10           18.74
```

When I tried

```
string=string.strip('.')
string=string.replace(',','.')
float(string.strip().strip("'"))
```

The system returned me an error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0
-5.000.73\n1            15.60\n3            14.13\n4            12.53\n5            16.64\n6            22.48\n7            24.30\n8            24.88\n9            31.40\n10
```

The data are loaded from a csv, and the delimiter is `,`

1. How can I easily convert to a float, considering that \n7, \n10,..., \n160000 are not regularly increased?
2. Why I get this kind of problem?
3. If I open my csv with Jupyter or on excel I cannot see `/n32`, but only something like this 
   `"01/01/2018","16,60","Spain"`,  I know that `/n` is used for giving a vertical space, but I don't know how to deal with it, I noticed that is related with the index

I read this questions, tried other solutions, but none solved my problem:

[numpy.loadtxt, ValueError: could not convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729210/numpy-loadtxt-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

[ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0,274697\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013867/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-0-274697-n)

[How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

[Python convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219479/python-convert-string-to-float)

[Python. ValueError could not convert string to float:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158099/python-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

[ValueError: could not convert string to float in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559522/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-in-pyspark)

Comment: Just one remark: there is no `n7` in your string. There is `\n7`. Thta is different. `\n` is one character - the newline.

Comment: Please post a few more lines from the price column. Your error shows additional entries that might be needed to determine what is going on. Try posting 0 through 20.

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't code, but fix the comma issue in the dataframe before converting back to python

Comment: I see -5.000.73, is this even a valid float? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Unlike writing money for other denominations, you need to use periods for decimal points, and no commas. As @Prazy said, -5.000.73 is not a valid float number, and 5,000 will give you (5,0) due to how Python intepreters work (example: 5,132 will give you a tuple of `(5,132)`)

Comment: Also you should avoid using `string` as a variable name

Comment: I loaded the csv, price column could be positive or negative. I tried to use only periods, I read a question about it, but when I first stripped the period and then replaced the commas with the periods, the system returned this weird output `-5.000.73`

Comment: For -5.000,73 you need to remove a ',' (comma). I feel, the comma there is dividing them into units, hundreds...?

Comment: The comma in the raw csv divides units from decimal

Comment: so 15,60 is equal to 15.60?

Comment: So, after '.' (point) there is 000,73. Is it like tenth (0) hundredth(0) thousandth (0),
ten-thousandth (7) and Hundred-thousandth (3)?

Comment: @jhomr then the way he is coding is wrong.

Comment: That is my assumption. Deleted my old comment as I was unsure if I was already telling you things you knew ;)

Comment: @Andrea Ciufo I'm fairly sure your issue is that 5.000 should be 5000 and not 5,000, and the numbers after that have commas instead of decimals

Comment: Yes 15,60 is equal (after I replaced `,` with `.`)  to 15.60 , like fifteen euros and 60 cents  and, always from the raw csv -5.000,73  is minus five thousand euros and 73 cents, Yes but I don't know why the code does not strip and then replace

Comment: `strip()` only affects starting and ending characters

Comment: If you can edit the Csv in excel, choose the column and change the formatting to proper ####.## form then pass that Csv to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strip()` only removes leading and trailing characters. You can achieve that by using `replace()` instead:

```
string = "-5.000,73"
string = string.replace('.', '')
string = string.replace(',', '.')
# float(string.strip().strip("'"))
float(string)
```

> string.strip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this method is called on.

More information can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Also, I'm not sure why you are trying to strip apostrophe's as well, but the syntax for that should be `string.replace(''', '')`; I would wait until you are done stripping characters to convert it too a float using `float()`.

On a side note, you can use print statements in your code to see what is going wrong. As soon as I pasted your original code. It was apparent that the first period was not being removed from the string.

Comment: But, 

string = "-5.000,73"
string = string.replace('.', '') # Will replace . after 5 with ,
string = string.replace(',', '.') in your code replace both comma's with '.'

Comment: instead you can use this string = string.replace(',', '.',1)

string = -5.00,73

Comment: @Prazy you will need to be a little more specific. The OP did not give any real data to work with other than what he has posted. In this case, I assume he is trying to remove the period, and convert the comma into a period in order to represent currency in some form.

Comment: What you write as the answer will output -5.000.73 (which is not valid).

Comment: @Prazy directly cutting and pasting the code produces -5000.73 when you append a print statement to the end.

Comment: Ah did not see a blank in this. Sorry, string = string.replace('.', '')

Comment: @AndreaCiufo if this solved your issue, please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: @artomason sure I will try the code I also waited for other answers. I didn't put more real data because I followed this suggestion [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) that a user gave me

Answer (score 1):

Convert a list of numbers to float

```
    numbers = [
    '₹ 524.00',
    '₹ 5,000.00',
    '₹ 485.00',
    '₹ 800.00',
    '₹ 236.00',
    '₹ 2,000.00',
    '₹ 630.00',
    '₹ 385.00',
    '₹ 500.00',
    '₹ 629.00',
    '₹ 301.00',
    '₹ 141.00',
]

numbers = [(num[2:]) for num in numbers]
numbers = [float(num.replace(',', '').strip()) for num in numbers]
print(f'Amounts in the list: {numbers}')
```